# Why is $\text{Pr}(T^2 > X^2) = 2\text{Pr}(T>X)$ for $T$ being a $t$-distribution and $X$ any numerical value?

Tags: probability, t-distribution

Can someone please explain and derive (algebraically) how if T is a student's t-distribution and X is any arbitrary numerical value; how these two statements are:

$\text{Pr}(T^2 > X^2) = 2\text{Pr}(T>X)$

Comment: Actually the equation is only true if $X\ge 0$.

Comment: Is this for some subject? 1. Draw a picture. 2. For $X>0$, show what happens to the event $T< \,-X$ when you square both sides.

Comment: This isn't really a question about distributions or statistics: it's about working with square roots, as the preceding comments intimate.

Comment: Because $P(T<-x)=P(T>x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$T^2 > X^2 $ is equivalent to $|T|>|X|$, which is equivalent to $(T>|X|)\,or\,(T<-|X|)$, and $\text{Pr}(T>|X|)=\text{Pr}(T<-|X|)$ (as Did's comment pointed) because t-Student distribution is symmetrical about 0.

Therefore:

$\text{Pr}(T^2 > X^2) = \text{Pr}(|T|>|X|)= \text{Pr}(T>|X|)+\text{Pr}(T<-|X|) =2\text{Pr}(T>|X|)$

If $X>0$ then the last one equals  $2\text{Pr}(T>X)$.

Comment: ...Should alter that to "is symmetrical about 0".

Comment: @jbowman I always doubt between being precise and keeping it simple. I take your point but still wonder if it makes the answer easier to understand for people like the OP. Being precise surely pleases experienced people, but those people already know the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The relationship does not hold when X is allowed to be arbitrary: Suppose that $X<0$. Then $2\Pr(T>X) > 1 > \Pr(T^2>X^2)$. You must assume that $X\geq 0$, as others have noted.